# If $H$ a proper subgroup of $G$, with $|G|=p^n$ then $gHg^{-1}=H$ for some $g\in G-H$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have shown that for any normal subgroup $N$, we have $Z(N)$ nontrivial. If $Z(N)\not\subset H$ then any $g\in Z(N)-H$ works. I am struggling to argue in the case that $Z(N)\subset H$.

I've tried arguing using Orbit-Stabiliser and the conjugation action as I did for the first part, but I can't see how to apply this to $gHg^{-1}$.

Comment: In other words, you are asking whether every proper subgroup of a $p$-group is properly contained in its normalizer.

Answer (score 1):

Let us say that a group $G$ is an $N$-group if every proper subgroup $H$ is properly contained in its normalizer $N_G(H)$. Your question asks if every $p$-group is an $N$-group. We will prove this for a group $G$ of order $p^n$ by induction on $n$. First, notice that if $G$ is abelian, then $N_G(H) = G$ and so $G$ is an $N$-group. Therefore any group of order $p$ is an $N$-group (actually even of order $p^2$).

Now let $G$ have order $p^n$ for some $n > 1$, and let $H$ be a proper subgroup of $G$. As you have noticed $Z(G)$ is non-trivial, and if $Z(G) \cap H \neq \{e\}$, then we are done. Else, assume that $Z(G) \leq H$. Then $H/Z(G)$ is a proper subgroup of $G/Z(G)$, which is a group of order $p^k$ for some $k < n$. By induction, $H/Z(G)$ is properly contained in $N_{G/Z(G)}(H/Z(G))$. Using the correspondence theorem we have $N_{G/Z(G)}(H/Z(G)) = N_G(H)/Z(G)$, and so $H$ is properly contained in $N_G(H)$.

Comment: I really like this argument. I'm not familiar with the correspondence theorem - would it be correct to say that since there is some $gZ(G)\not\in H/Z(G)$ such that $gZ(G) \cdot H/Z(G) \cdot g^{-1}Z(G)$, then $\forall h\in H$ there is $h'\in H$ such that $ghg^{-1}Z(G)=h'Z(G)$, so if $Z(G)\subset H$ then $ghg^{-1}\in H$, so $gHg^{-1}=H$?

Comment: @frafour Unfortunately I don't see why $N_{G/Z(G)}(H/Z(G)) = N_{G}(H)/(Z(G)$. Could you help me out?

Comment: This is part of the correspondence theorem in group theory, which relates the behaviour of inclusions in a group with inclusions on a quotient, including how normality behaves. In this case the ambient group is $N_G(H)$. You can find it in any group theory textbook or on wikipedia